# Google App Engine asset pipeline standard environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, asset-pipeline

Is it possible to use the Ruby on Rails asset pipeline in Google App Engine when the app is deployed to a standard (not flexible) environment? I know precompilation happens when deploying to a flexible environment but I can't get it to work for the standard environment.

Comment: I'm also struggling to get Rails working in GAE Standard. Always a problem with missing assets. I've tried a lot of different things, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the default configuration of `app.yaml` is preventing a crucial file being uploaded to GAE.

Specifically the [`skip_files`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) section has some defaults that are preventing all dot-files from being uploaded, including the sprockets manifest file: `/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-5y483543959430890.json`. Without this file, Rails assumes that assets haven't been precompiled.

You need to override the default `skip_files` configuration with something that doesn't prevent the sprockets manifest from being uploaded, but still blocks things like `.git/*`.

This is working for me now, but I'm sure it could be further refined:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\.git/.*$
```

Comment: Woot! It works. It would be nice if Google documented the `skip_files` section for their Ruby documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Check the full documentation here: [Ruby in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/quickstart).

Note that the Ruby Standard Environment it's on Beta stage, so keep in mind that it might get changed overtime.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `skip_files` section of app.yaml, you can instead create a `.gcloudignore` file and add a line for `/public/assets`. If this directory is not present, the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/serving-static-files) say:

> The Ruby runtime executes rake assets:precompile during deployment to generate static assets and sets the RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES environment variable to enable static file serving in production.